# Business Objects Ent.report metadata connection strings

Tags: business-objects, business-objects-sdk

Is there a way to get from Business Objects Enterprise XI R2 Report Names and their connections information? I heard that there is a way to query metadata, but not even sure where and how to begin.
Google does not return any particular information on that subject

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooh. Finally got it:

```
Select  SI_NAME,SI_PROCESSINFO.SI_LOGON_INFO 
From CI_INFOOBJECTS 
Where SI_PROGID='CrystalEnterprise.Report' And SI_INSTANCE=0
```